# Why can I not see two of the iframes AT ALL?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I decided to ask here before I get completely crazy over this. The title is self-explanatory.

Here is the html part:

```
<div id="iframeList">
  <iframe src="list.php">
</div>
<div id="iframeDownloads">
  <iframe src="../mailer/print/index.php" name="downloads" id="downloads">
</div>
<div id="iframeErrors">
  <iframe src="../admin/errors.php">
</div>
```

This is the entire CSS:

```
html,body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #dd2222; background-color: #fffdf9;  font-size: 1.0em;  margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }


div#iframeList{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; width: 80%; height: 100%;
  border: none; padding-top: 0px;
   box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#iframeDownloads{
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  top: 0%; left: 0%; width: 20%; height: 60%;
  border: none; padding-top: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}


div#iframeErrors{
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  top: 60%; left: 80%; width: 20%; height: 40%;
  border: none; padding-top: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I know that the CSS file is imported and used by the HTML page.

Also, this is the source or the HTML page. There, everything after (and including) the first

```
</div>
```

is grayed out. It is not displayed here.

```
<div id="iframeList">
  <iframe src="list.php">
</div>
<div id="iframeDownloads">
    <iframe src="../mailer/print/index.php" name="downloads" id="downloads">
</div>
<div id="iframeErrors">
    <iframe src="../admin/errors.php">
</div>
```

The page only shows the first iframe, and it is in a small box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must close iframe tag.

```
<div id="iframeList">
  <iframe src="list.php"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="iframeDownloads">
    <iframe src="../mailer/print/index.php" name="downloads" id="downloads"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="iframeErrors">
    <iframe src="../admin/errors.php"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I closed all three. Now i just see the two first iframes, but still as small boxes.

Comment: I can see all three in fact.

Comment: @7segment happy to hear. don't forget to upvote and accept answer if it's working for you.

Comment: @7segment You can also click upvote (This answer is useful) too.